# How do I nest the same custom directive with FreeMarker？

Tags: freemarker, directive

This is my template:

```
<@base64>head://<@base64>{"add":"addr","aid":"0","host":"sefse.sdf.xyz"}</@base64></@base64>
```

This is my directive:

```
class Base64Directive : TemplateDirectiveModel {


    @Throws(TemplateException::class, IOException::class)
    override fun execute(env: Environment,
                         params: Map<*, *>, loopVars: Array<TemplateModel?>,
                         body: TemplateDirectiveBody?) { // Check if no parameters were given:
        if (!params.isEmpty()) {
            throw TemplateModelException(
                    "This directive doesn't allow parameters.")
        }
        if (loopVars.size != 0) {
            throw TemplateModelException(
                    "This directive doesn't allow loop variables.")
        }
        // If there is non-empty nested content:
        if (body != null) {
            // Executes the nested body. Same as <#nested> in FTL, except
            // that we use our own writer instead of the current output writer.
            body.render(Base64FilterWriter(env.out))
        } else {
            throw RuntimeException("missing body")
        }
    }

    /**
     * A [Writer] that transforms the character stream to upper case
     * and forwards it to another [Writer].
     */
    private class Base64FilterWriter internal constructor(out: Writer) : Writer() {
        private val out: Writer = out
        @Throws(IOException::class)
        override fun write(cbuf: CharArray, off: Int, len: Int) {
            var transformedCbuf = String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(String(cbuf).toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8).clone()))
            out.write(transformedCbuf)
        }

        @Throws(IOException::class)
        override fun flush() {
            out.flush()
        }

        @Throws(IOException::class)
        override fun close() {
            out.close()
        }

    }
}
```

There are two directive which nested with each other. When I run my code, it cannot compile the directive pair from inside(<@base64>{"add":"addr","aid":"0","host":"sefse.sdf.xyz"}/@base64) to outside(<@base64>head://base64-after/@base64).

How can I make this compile work from inside to outside?

Comment: What exactly the problem is? I'm not sure what you mean by "cannot compile" above. You got some error message?

Comment: @ddekany No error message. "cannot compile" means the compiler cannot compile as I expect. My problem is How can i make the compiler analysis the nest directive like the example above.

Comment: You want to say that there's no exception, you just don't get the expected output? That has nothing to do with compiling. Anyway, I think I know why: you mustn't close `env.out`.  In general you shouldn't close stuff that you haven't opened.

Comment: @ddekany Yeah, there's no exception. I think I may used it by wrong way.